# Sequelize join giving A is not associated with B

Tags: sequelize.js

In my model definition I have:

```
tableA.hasMany(tableB);
```

So in tableB I have the field "tableAId".

However, when I try to run this code:

```
return models.tableB.findAll({include: {model: models.tableA}}).then(function(result){
    if(result){
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
    else{
        return Promise.reject(false);
    }
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

I get the error:

```
A is not associated with B
```

So defining that tableA has many tableB is not enough in order to join the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `belongsTo` association inside `tableB` model, referencing `tableA`.

```
tableB.belongsTo(tableA);
```

Then you will be able to include `tableA` while querying `tableB`.

Comment: It doesnt seem possible to do it with migration? Im using sequelize cli migration to modify schema. But could not find a way to do it here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/

Comment: If you have `tableAid` column inside `tableB` (as a foreign key to `tableA`) table, then you do not have to modify schema. You need to use `belongsTo` in order to create the Sequelize association between those two models so that you can query `tableB` model with associated `tableA`

Comment: Yes but when do I need to do this "belongsTo"? Before the query in the question?

Comment: When you define the `tableB` model - look through the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto)